# How to return a nested type of a type that was passed in

Tags: typescript, generics

Say I have a type `Person` with their name, age, and a list of all their friends.

```js
type Person = {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  friends: Person[];
}
```

Then say I have a function `getFriendsWithSameAge`. This function only needs the age prop in order to do what it needs to do. So instead of taking as a parameter `Person` it takes a `MinimalPerson` ie:

```js
type MinimalPerson = {
  age: number;
  friends: MinimalPerson[];
}

export function getFriendsWithSameAge(person: MinimalPerson) {
  return person.friends.filter(friend => friend.age === person.age);
}
```

This is nice because `getFriendsWithSameAge` is very flexible in terms of input arguments. You can pass in any sort of Person object as long as it has at the very least `age` and `friends` defined. This is a very common scenario when using GraphQl.

The issue comes with the return type. This code complains:

```js
const person: Person = { name: 'John', age: 32, friends: [...] }

const friend = getFriendsWithSameAge(person)[0];
const name = friend.name; // error, function call destroys typing, doesn't know what name is
```

I was hoping I could solve this with generics by preserving the types that were passed in and then returning them like:

```js
export function getFriendsWithSameAge<T extends MinimalPerson>(person T): T['friends'] { // obviously doesn't work
  return person.friends.filter(friend => friend.age === person.age);
}
```

but I can't seem to figure out how to type the return type.

edit: My attempted solution above works just fine. My issue was that `T['friends']` does not work if T is nullable which is a detail I left out for the sake of this question.

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAChBOBnA9gOygXigbwFBSlQEMBbCALikWHgEtUBzAbnyiIYsIFcSAjBFgQBmdCKgAmiSnCRoA2gF0WAX1y5QkKAFl6tEkQA2MlOix4C7Tqh794gqCNpjJlHaj2Hj8pblW4IAB5gyPDADlyoAMbAtGhQHMAAYqISiADqtMAAFgDKpBAAghwAFJCyqK66+kYIJgCUOKzwEMBc8OhlJgB0js6IPbQGwAjFvRKYAHwOKeJdlpgYWJ1ocxx1KmqRaNRQyxWwtXFmhPmUAOQAUshZqGcANGwclADMAEwPYy5Qcl2-ClB+LaoHafTDxFrJJypDLZPJkIoQUqHVB1OQABh8QJ2xDIYM+XRxECYUAA9CSoAh4CEPhForF0JFDAYoOIINQqSBEFANPQGA9xMg2bcwgBrVDIADuUAlWSIYUJUFoiCAA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, in my playground your solutions works: [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsTIN4BQyyIcAthAFzIZhSgDmA3EcnA1SQK5kBG0LYjHoQQAEwzUAYiPEBtALosAvgQKhIsRChnBRY-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) [updated]

Comment: Interesting. Unfortunately I am using generated GraphQL types and I cannot change the definition of Person to extend MinimalPerson, as far as I know.

Comment: Actually, even without extending MinimalPerson the code works :) you don't need to edit any definition at all. I forgot to delete it after working on it, sorry but it's the first time I use Playground and I don't know why it didn't save my changes ahah

Comment: You're right, I found my issue, it was unrelated, will update post